# Isotope updating to V2, how to toggle size and layot

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-isotope

http://bit.ly/19GXxDy under the *Etc* section of the filters, there is a **toggle size** function. using this we made a page as a basic sample to build an HTML page with portfolio vector logos, upgrading to V2 using the sites samples is failing. Are we using the wrong methods?

What's changed and what are we doing wrong. We're trying to upgrade to V2 and unable to get the same toggle tile size to work in V2,

```
  // V1 toggle variable sizes of all elements
  $('#toggle-sizes').find('a').click(function(){
    $container
      .toggleClass('variable-sizes')
      .isotope('reLayout');
    return false;
  });





  // in V2 change size of all item by toggling class, doesnt work
 $container.on( 'click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('variable-sizes');
    $container.isotope('layout');
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you have defined your variable $container in your code? What seems to be happening with your v2 code is you have a click on the $container toggle the class 'variable-sizes', on the $container itself, which is $(this) in your code, not your link 'a'.

you want to do this instead:

```
$container.on( 'click','a', function() {
$(this).toggleClass('variable-sizes');
$container.isotope('layout');
});
```

An example of your code in a jsfiddle would be more helpful to answer your question.

Comment: Thanks, its working although only some of the tiles in the viewport toggle

Comment: Yes I have $container. I was porting the very same demo page here http://bit.ly/19GXxDy it has some financial data for the data elements. @Macsupport thanks to you, the code has it working now _in the viewport_ . However can you tell me how to target/toggle all the tiles in the page, or at least how to toggle all the tiles and relayout (has V2 changed from relayout to layout method, wish there was table mapping old and new methods)

Comment: I would need to see an example. A link or a jsfiddle.

Comment: can you fiddle up a small sample on the toggle size for V2 or share a snippet.                                                                                                                          -      Is the `variable-sizes`  in the code `toggleClass('variable-sizes');`  a _div data-item_?